# SCORM 2004 ADL Test Suite Error

Tags: parameters, manifest, scorm, scorm2004, argument-dependent-lookup

> ***tldnr:** need a variation to allow "/" in parameter object on organization item;*

When doing a "Content Package Conformance Test" I receve the following error when for the parameters attribute. This is a necessary attribute for the content to function, but will not validate as long as I have the "/" in there. I have tested the package on the SCORM cloud, and it loads and launches as intended, but I need to validate it as well. Is there a variation I could use that would maintain the "/" but allow it to be properly validated?

> ERROR: [?first=0&dir=dir/subdir] does not adhere to the syntax defined by IMS CP 1.1.4 and SCORM for the "parameters" attribute

Variations Tried:
?dir=dir//subdir&first=0 //same error
?dir=dir\/subdir&first=0 //same error
?dir=dir\subdir&first=0 //same error
?dir=dir/subdir&first=0 //same error
?dir=dir⁄subdir&first=0 //invalidates the xml

Additionally Tried:

%3Ffirst%3D0%26wd%3Ddir%2Fsubdir  //same error
?first=0&wd=dir%2Fsubdir //same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a url encoded version:

%3Fdir%3Ddir%2Fsubdir%26first%3D0

Comment: I've tried this:  "?first=0&amp;wd=dir%2Fsubdir", but it causes the javaApplet to fail. see error below

Comment: also tried full urlencode as you suggested, but still receive the same error, appended these to the OP

Comment: Sounds like it could be an error in the CTS. Have you submitted the problem to ADL?

Comment: not yet. I was trying to ensure it wasn't something I was screwing up first.